# Illustrator won't import gradients from .emf file, made in visio

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have several images in .emf format that were made by another designer in Visio. When I open them in Illustrator, the shapes remain, but the gradients are gone. As I have never used Visio before, I am wondering what made the gradients incompatible with Illustrator, and if there is any way to convert/fix the gradients to work using only adobe programs.

I have tried converting the file into an svg. The SVG shows the gradients when opened in a browser, but still wont show when I open it with Illustrator.

[image: with gradients]

[image: in illustrator]

Comment: Is it possible you could share a offending file?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could share the file, but if you have a way, I can

Comment: It appears this weirdness is a known issue with opening EMF files that contain gradients (which are actually EMF+ files) in Illustrator. [Source.](http://www.visiozone.com/?p=349)